# Showing content on pages without taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have setup a drupal site so that a block is showing specific content on pages with the same taxonomy term as the block.

Now I am trying to get some sort of default content for pages without taxonomy terms. 
I want the block to show all the content without taxonomy terms attached on pages without any terms attached (such as the front page and some sub pages the client makes himself).

The block in question is a slider and it would be silly if the client would see the slider disappear on pages he creates due to taxonomy.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

This should be fairly straight forward

1. Create a new view that displays all the content without a taxonomy term,
2. In the existing block view look under the advanced settings for no results behaviour and click add. In here you can add a view to display if there are no results so simple select your view that you created in step 1.